# Use variable as key in dictionary lookup in format string

Tags: python

I know that it's possible to do the following

```
d = {}
d['foo'] = 'bar'
print("foo: {d[foo]}".format(**vars()))
foo: bar
```

But I'm having trouble accomplishing the following

```
d = {}
key = 'foo'
d[key] = 'bar'
print("{key}: {d[key]}".format(**vars()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'key'
```

I'm expecting the output "foo: bar"
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Joran's answer, and the comment to it from DSM: you can apply basic hacks to get a not very robust system. If you want to do this sort of thing robustly, you need to use a templating system that was designed to handle it.

Jinja 2 is one such (jinja.pocoo.org/). Google reveals many more: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+templating

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this isn't possible in the templating that is part of the python standard library. If you use jinja the code below is one of achieving what you want.

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = '{% set lookup = d[key] %} {{key}} {{lookup}}'
print Template(t).render(**vars())
```

**output**

```
foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 "*key*: {d[*key*]}".replace("*key*",key).format(**vars())
```

maybe ...

(edit: added asterix to key to make it less likely to replace monkey :P )

Comment: You'd probably have to use a regex instead to avoid accidentally replacing the `key` in `monkey`.

Comment: @DSM You mean you want to create your own template system now?

Comment: @Marcin: ?  I simply meant that as written, `replace` is a little dangerous.  I tend to use `string.Template` or `format` interpolation, myself, and adjust my data structures to fit.

Comment: meh you certainly have a point DSM ... but i dont want to go down that path .... have him call it k_e_y instead would probably work ... just pick a more unique name that isnt likely to showup ...

Comment: @DSM And what I mean is that if you start crafting regexes to do this, you're beginning your own template engine.

Comment: @Marcin: if you like, imagine adding "but don't do that because it's far too much work to get right" to my original comment, which is more or less how I think everyone should feel as soon as regexes get involved.

Comment: there basically fixed the issue for this case :P

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works, but is kind of ugly:

```
print("{key}: {}".format(eval("{d}['{key}']".format(**vars())), **vars()))
```

Output:

```
foo: bar
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm expecting the output "foo: bar"

Comment: @kylejmcintyre: Oops. Fixed.